# Text zoom in and out function

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have some text in textView in Activity .By cliking the zoombutton i need to get the Zoom of text.
i have used the following code  in clickListenser

```
                            pixel=pixel+20;
            text.setTextSize(pixel);
```

but i didn't get the zoom of that text.

can any one give the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw your text on `ImageView` instead of using `TextView` and then just use zoom-in and zoom-out animations for it. Here is a [tutorial](http://jongladwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/android-how-to-zoom-in-zoom-out-images.html) for this

Comment: Thank yoy for your reply,i am getting the dynamic data ..i wanrt to show that data as in Activity ..

Comment: i have zoom button is there ,when i we click on button , the text size wil increase accordingly.
Any other solution